# Директива для обработки большого количества DOM-событий в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Допустим, есть схема в формате SVG,  на которой  много  разных элементов, для каждого элемента надо добавить событие click, как  **правильно** (**производительно**) добавить событие на сотни элементов.
Оправдано ли использовать такую директиву, или же проще средствами JQuery

```js
var app = angular.module('pl', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive('rect', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("click", function(event) {
      console.log("clicks");

    });
  };
})
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <svg id="svgg" width="600px" height="600px">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="10px" height="10px"/><rect x="0" y="10" width="10px" height="10px"/><rect x="0" y="20" width="10px" height="10px"/><rect x="0" y="30" width="10px" height="10px"/>
...
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/P97VaDMvyJ63xMxh4KjE?p=preview

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Из-за соображения производительности я порекомендовал бы использовать метод делегирования события. Этот метод работает достаточно прост:

1. Привязывается событие к родителю, в котором расположено множество элементов
2. В обработчике этого события проверяется `event.target`, то есть проверяется  кто именно вызвал это событие (тег `rect`). Это делает на случай если родитель имеет другие элементы, которые не нужно обрабатывать.
3. Выполняется логика

Этот метод сокращает потребление памяти, потому "прослушивается" одно событие одного элемента, а не 100 штук.

Реализовать это можно как с помощью нативного JavaScript'a или jQuery, либо с помощью AngularJS, только директиву надо добавлять для родителя `rect'ов`, к `svg` как вариант.